# Im trying to build a menu that has collapsible options, but the dom does not update even when state data updates

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [arrayOfQuestions, setArrayOfQuestions] = useState([
  {
    q: 'Are your products safe to use?',
    a: 'Yes.',
    hidden: true
  },
  {
    q: 'Are your products safe to use?',
    a: 'Yes.',
    hidden: true
  },
  {
    q: 'Are your products safe to use?',
    a: 'Yes.',
    hidden: true
  },
  {
    q: 'Are your products safe to use?',
    a: 'Yes.',
    hidden: true
  },
])

const toggleItemOpenAndClose = (e) => {
  let array = arrayOfQuestions
  array[e.target.id].hidden = !array[e.target.id].hidden
  setArrayOfQuestions(array)
}

return (
    <div>
        <Layout 
        bgImage={metaData.heroImage.childImageSharp.fluid} 
        header='Frequently Asked Questions'>
          <div className='page-container'>
            <div className="content-container">
              {
                arrayOfQuestions.map((question,i) => {
                  return (
                    <div id={i} key={`id${i}`} onClick={toggleItemOpenAndClose} className='block-container'>
                      <div id={i} className='white smallerheader'>
                        {question.q}
                      </div>
                      {
                        question.hidden ?
                        null :
                        <div id={i} className='white paragraph'>
                          <br/>
                          {question.a}
                        </div>
                      }
                    </div>
                  )
                })
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        </Layout>
    </div>
)
```

}

Im using Gatsby and react hooks.

Im trying to build a collapsible menu (an faq) sort of like a menu, so that when you click on one of the options, it expands and shows you the answer associated with the question. However, I'm having trouble making it work in real time. whenever i click on the option, my data updates, but the dom itself doesnt update when i click on the option. then, when i change something in the code, the app updates (hot reloader?) and then the dom updates. As far as i understand it, when i change state in real time, the dom should also update in real time, but I can't understand why its not in this case. Has anyone experienced something like this before?

Comment: Can you post your layout.js file?

Comment: the layout code is purely presentational, its just a header and a footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be updating state directly. This should be your toggle code

```html
const toggleItemOpenAndClose = (e) => {
  // This will create a new array and with all new objects to preserve immutability
  let newArray = arrayOfQuestions.map(x => {
    return {... x}
  }
  newArray[e.target.id].hidden = !newArray[e.target.id].hidden
  setArrayOfQuestions(newArray)
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If you used my answer, would you mind marking it as accepted? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Make a copy `arrayOfQuestions` like so,

`let array = [...arrayOfQuestions]`

Why ?

What you're updating is an object property but it's still belongs to the same array ref. When you spread over the array, you will unpack the object references in your array and pack them in a new array due to those `[]` and then setting this new array will actually trigger the render.

In case you want to make copy of the objects as well in your array, use `map` as suggested by @Doug Hill which I think looks better.

But in your case simply spreading will also work for now. Things get messy when there are nesting depths of objects and then consider using libraries which supply you with deep cloning utilities.